# Perl file list compare

Tags: perl, argv

I need to iterate through and compare all files passed in as command line arguments in a perl script.

For example:

```
./script f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt
```

I'll need to compare

```
f1 & f2,
f1 & f3,
f2 & f3,
```

So that all files are compared to each other in some way, and not repeated.

I can do the internal 'comparing' of the files just fine, it's the way to get the files paired up which is the problem for me.

Any help to discover a way for this would be muchly appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like combinatorics... maybe a job for [Algorithm::Combinatorics](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Combinatorics)?

Comment: Could you post the script you already tried to wrote!?

Answer (score 1):

You just want to compare every argument against every argument past itself. The ones before it would have been compared already, so you just have to look beyond.  Something like this:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @ARGV; ++$i)
{
    for (my $j = $i + 1; $j < @ARGV; ++$j)
    {
        my $f1 = $ARGV[$i];
        my $f2 = $ARGV[$j];
        say "Comparing $f1 to $f2";
    }
}
```

Comment: Cleaner: `for my $i (0..$#ARGV) { for my $j ($i+1..$#ARGV) { ... } }`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that comparing "p" and "q" is the same as comparing "q" and "p", then you can do something like this.  Here, `@filelist` is a changing list of files that haven't yet been the left-hand side of the compare.  In each iteration of the outer loop, we take one element out of that, and compare it against all the rest.

```
my @filelist = @ARGV;
while (@filelist) {
  my $p = shift @filelist;
  foreach my $q (@filelist) {
    compare($p, $q);
  }
}
```

You could do the same thing with indices instead.  Here, `$p` counts from 0 to the number of files you have, and `$q` starts counting from `$p`.

```
foreach my $p (0..$#ARGV) {
  foreach my $q ($p+1..$#ARGV) {
    compare($ARGV[$p], $ARGV[$q]);
  }
}
```

If comparing "p" and "q" is different than comparing "q" and "p", then it gets a bit easier:

```
foreach my $p (@ARGV) {
  foreach my $q (@ARGV) {
    compare($p, $q) unless $p eq $q;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can also use `while (my $p = shift @filelist) { ... }`